# nuxtjs client_side problem old browsers like firefox 34

Tags: babeljs, nuxt.js, babel-polyfill

i have a problem with nuxt project in old browsers like Firefox version 34
anything i added on client side, dont show on browser
everything are good on all new browsers

anyone can help me ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you talk a bit more about your use case here?

Answer (score 0):

There a 0% percent of usage of Firefox 34 based on [Can I Use's stats](https://caniuse.com/usage-table) and on top of it, Firefox is an [evergreen browser](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1058530) for a long time already (v5) meaning that it should auto-update itself (not like Safari).

So you could backtrace it all until then I guess, but you'll need to need to reach [1st December 2014](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/34.0/releasenotes/) to achieve this. Which is a pretty hardcore task, on top of it not being simple to keep a website with a good enough performance.